# Best cross browser compatibility tool for Linux machine?

Tags: browser, cross-browser, cross-compiling, fedora, rpm

I need a best browser compatibility checking tool for my linux machine ( dont want online checking tool) .

Wanted a tool which should be run in my local. Is there any tool ? If yes please recommend.

Regards,
ArunRaj.

Comment: _"**Some questions are still off-topic** : Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_

Comment: @huMpty duMpty : I am really sorry for this. What to do now ?

Comment: I am not so sure what to do apart from deleting the question. But before that,  you can always ask what to do in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also tried to solve this issue a few weeks ago. After some hours of research i came to the conclusion that sand-boxing or building virtual-machines would be the best solution for me.

I can also recommend **ievms** script to install virtual machines for running IE6 up to IE10 with a single command:
[Automated installation of the Microsoft IE App Compat virtual machines](https://github.com/xdissent/ievms)

The Images are provided by Microsoft itself:
[Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Image](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575)

Comment: Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Image provides 90 days. After the 90 days what do i do ? May I re download another new VM or May I install the VM again ?

Answer (score 2):

For realistic testing, think about using virtual machines and virtual environments like Vmware Player or VirtualBox (https://www.virtualbox.org/). You can install different operating systems and different browsers to see what your page looks like.